# Move Files on Remote FTP Server

Tags: windows, ftp

When connected to an ftp server with the Windows command line FTP client, is there any way to copy or move a file from one directory on the server, to another directory also on the server?

Ideally, without using the client machine as an intermediate location. (e.g. `get SomeDir\MyFile.txt temp.txt` then `put temp.txt AnotherDir\MyFile.txt`)

Comment: Since we're talking about the Windows in-built FTP client, try using the Rename command. ie: `rename <sourcePath>\file.ext <targetPath>\file.ext`. Unfortunately I don't currently have a plain ftp server available to test this. :)

Comment: Yep, that works.  Didn't occur to me, and the documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687754.aspx) doesn't exactly make it obvious.  Want to post an actual answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're talking about the Windows in-built FTP client, try using the [Rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490677.aspx) command.

ie: `rename <sourcePath>\file.ext <targetPath>\file.ext`

> Syntax
>
> **rename** *FileName NewFileName*
>
> Parameters
>
> ***FileName***    : Specifies the file that you want to
>   rename.
>
> ***NewFileName***    : Specifies the new file name.
>
> ***? rename***  : Displays help for the **rename** command.